# Is it correct way that "ifconfig eth0 down" or "ip link set eth0 down" to simulate unplugged network cable

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, disconnect

I am working on to simulate network connection fail scenario between two virtual machines. Is it correct way that "ifconfig eth0 down" or "ip link set eth0 down" to simulate unplugged network cable. Is there alternative without down interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it can to simulate unplugged network cable

Comment: After all my search and sagaf's contribution, I am answered that it is a useable way to simulate unplugged ethernet network case.